# How do I make an intro slider like the one from the homes.com app in Titanium Alloy

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

Is there an existing module to do this? How do you get different layers to interact like that do in this? Notice that the woman and image box appear to float in front of the background. The dotted line from the background ballon to the front one animates with the slide of the finger across the screen. The two balloons are not on the same layer.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNFF1VvsxzY

Homes.com is a titanium alloy app: http://www.tidev.io/2014/10/13/this-week-in-titanium-mobile-development-13-oct-2014/

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use scrollable view.

here are the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView)

Hope it helps.